# Array inside array get object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, filter

hello friends I have below array and I want to get region array item which displayName have Dubai I tried with below code but not working

```js
this.props = {
  countryListData: [
    {
      "country": {
        "countryCode": "AE",
        "displayName": "United Arab Emirates",
        "repositoryId": "AE"
      },
      "regions": [
        {
          "regionCode": "AE-FU",
          "displayName": "Fujairah",
          "repositoryId": "AE-FU",
          "abbreviation": "FU"
        },
        {
          "regionCode": "AE-DU",
          "displayName": "Dubai",
          "repositoryId": "AE-DU",
          "abbreviation": "DU"
        },
        {
          "regionCode": "AE-UQ",
          "displayName": "Umm al-Quwain",
          "repositoryId": "AE-UQ",
          "abbreviation": "UQ"
        },
        {
          "regionCode": "AE-AJ",
          "displayName": "Ajman",
          "repositoryId": "AE-AJ",
          "abbreviation": "AJ"
        },
        {
          "regionCode": "AE-AZ",
          "displayName": "Abu Dhabi",
          "repositoryId": "AE-AZ",
          "abbreviation": "AZ"
        },
        {
          "regionCode": "AE-RK",
          "displayName": "Ras al-Khaimah",
          "repositoryId": "AE-RK",
          "abbreviation": "RK"
        },
        {
          "regionCode": "AE-SH",
          "displayName": "Sharjah",
          "repositoryId": "AE-SH",
          "abbreviation": "SH"
        }
      ],
      "repositoryId": "100003"
    }
  ]
};

for (let index = 0; index < this.props.countryListData.length; index++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < this.props.countryListData[index].regions.length; j++) {
    console.log("Region Name --->", this.props.countryListData[index].regions[j].displayName);

  }
}
```

I am getting error like region is undefined Anyone help me how i can get

Comment: Why does `countryListData` contain only one element? Can it contain more elements? Do you want to search all containing elements? Can you have duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
const list = [
    {
        "country": {
            "countryCode": "AE",
            "displayName": "United Arab Emirates",
            "repositoryId": "AE"
        },
        "regions": [
            {
                "regionCode": "AE-FU",
                "displayName": "Fujairah",
                "repositoryId": "AE-FU",
                "abbreviation": "FU"
            },
            {
                "regionCode": "AE-DU",
                "displayName": "Dubai",
                "repositoryId": "AE-DU",
                "abbreviation": "DU"
            },
            {
                "regionCode": "AE-UQ",
                "displayName": "Umm al-Quwain",
                "repositoryId": "AE-UQ",
                "abbreviation": "UQ"
            },
            {
                "regionCode": "AE-AJ",
                "displayName": "Ajman",
                "repositoryId": "AE-AJ",
                "abbreviation": "AJ"
            },
            {
                "regionCode": "AE-AZ",
                "displayName": "Abu Dhabi",
                "repositoryId": "AE-AZ",
                "abbreviation": "AZ"
            },
            {
                "regionCode": "AE-RK",
                "displayName": "Ras al-Khaimah",
                "repositoryId": "AE-RK",
                "abbreviation": "RK"
            },
            {
                "regionCode": "AE-SH",
                "displayName": "Sharjah",
                "repositoryId": "AE-SH",
                "abbreviation": "SH"
            }
        ],
        "repositoryId": "100003"
    }
];
console.log(list[0].regions.find(r => r.displayName === "Dubai"));
```

Is there a reason for the outer array container? It seems redundant given the data structure.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following function chain:

```
this.props = {
  countryListData: [
    {
      "country": {
        "countryCode": "AE",
        "displayName": "United Arab Emirates",
        "repositoryId": "AE"
      },
      "regions": [
        {
          "regionCode": "AE-FU",
          "displayName": "Fujairah",
          "repositoryId": "AE-FU",
          "abbreviation": "FU"
        },
        {
          "regionCode": "AE-DU",
          "displayName": "Dubai",
          "repositoryId": "AE-DU",
          "abbreviation": "DU"
        },
        {
          "regionCode": "AE-UQ",
          "displayName": "Umm al-Quwain",
          "repositoryId": "AE-UQ",
          "abbreviation": "UQ"
        },
        {
          "regionCode": "AE-AJ",
          "displayName": "Ajman",
          "repositoryId": "AE-AJ",
          "abbreviation": "AJ"
        },
        {
          "regionCode": "AE-AZ",
          "displayName": "Abu Dhabi",
          "repositoryId": "AE-AZ",
          "abbreviation": "AZ"
        },
        {
          "regionCode": "AE-RK",
          "displayName": "Ras al-Khaimah",
          "repositoryId": "AE-RK",
          "abbreviation": "RK"
        },
        {
          "regionCode": "AE-SH",
          "displayName": "Sharjah",
          "repositoryId": "AE-SH",
          "abbreviation": "SH"
        }
      ],
      "repositoryId": "100003"
    }
  ]
};

this.props.countryListData.map(c => c.regions.filter((r)=> r.displayName === 'Dubai')).flat()[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mapping to get region array item which displayName have 'Dubai'

```
        this.props.countryListData.map((it) =>
            it.regions.map((Arr) => {
              if (Arr.displayName === "Dubai"){
                 console.log(Arr);
                } 
             })
          )
```